# balance numpy X and y dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy ndarrays; classic machine learning use case:

`x` is a matrix of shape `(n, m)`:

```
x = np.array([
    [   0,   3, 42],
    [ 0.2, 1.7,  3],
    [ 0.1, 1.3,  4],
    [   7,   7,  7]
])
```

`y` is a boolean vector of length `n`:

```
y = np.array([False, False, True, False])
```

How can I (elegantly) drop rows in `x` and `y` such that there's an equal number of `True` and `False` values in `y`? Each element in `y` coresponds to a row in `x`, so regardless of what is discarded, the same rows and order should be preserved for both `x` and `y`. For speed purposes, I would prefer to keep as much of it in numpy as possible.

---

For this example, the result would look like the following:

```
x = np.array([
    [   0,   3, 42],
    [ 0.1, 1.3,  4]
])
y = np.array([False, True])
```

As there was one of each flag, `True` and `False`, only one row for each flag was preserved. In this example, it retained the first instance of each flag.

Comment: When you say even, do you mean number of True == number of False, or do you mean that the size of y should be divisible by 2?

Comment: When you provide array data, please provide it as an array, not some sort of table that I then have to figure out how to use in my code.

Comment: equal number of trues and false. Also, will do

Comment: I've edited your question. Hopefully you find that to be acceptable. Also, I answered with the assumption you just stated. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Just finished, it's perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the number of `True` and `False` elements in `y`:

```
t = np.count_nonzero(y)
f = y.size - t
```

Then you want to figure out which elements to trim off. If `t > f`, you want to remove the first (or last) `t - f` `True` elements from `y`. If `t < f`, you will want to remove the first (or last) `f - t` `False` elements from `y`. Start by computing a mask of the elements you want to remove:

```
if t >= f:
    mask = y
    n = t - f
else:
    mask = ~y
    n = f - t
```

You can find the first, last, or any other subset of `n` elements of `mask` by converting it to a list of indices:

```
if n:
    i = np.flatnonzero(mask)[-n:]  # or [:n]
else:
    i = []
```

Given the subset of indices, removing elements from `x` and `y` is pretty simple:

```
x = np.delete(x, i, axis=0)
y = np.delete(y, i)
```